# How to clear AWS RDS Aurora MySQL local storage?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, aws, aws-aurora

I got a warning message about running out of AWS RDS local storage.

> The free storage capacity for DB Instance: {MY INSTANCE NAME} is low
> at 2% of the provisioned storage [Provisioned Storage: 157.36 GB, Free
> Storage: 3.35 GB]. You may want to increase the provisioned storage to
> address this issue.

According to the AWS document, local storage depends on instance type and can be increased by scale up : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/aurora-mysql-local-storage/?nc1=h_ls

But, I would like to clear the local storage instead of scaling up the instance because only one instance of the read cluster has insufficient local storage.

I restarted Aurora instance but the local storage is still almost full.

How can I clear local storage?

It's MySQL version is 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

I asked to AWS about this issue and got answers.

It was a bug on oscar5.6.mysql_aurora.1.23.2 version.

Because of the bug, the size of the log file continued to increase.

The bug was solved on 2.10.2 version.

I upgraded the Aurora MySQL cluster from oscar5.6.mysql_aurora.1.23.2 to aurora-mysql:5.7.mysql_aurora.2.10.2.

Then, I created new instances on the same cluster and deleted old instances. - [BingbngKim](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/252902/bingbongkim)

Comment: What was the bug? Is there a bug report or at least a release notes describing it and its fix?