How can I find what's eating so much space in Postgres in AWS RDS Aurora?
Essentially when I run
SELECT
   pg_size_pretty(SUM(pg_total_relation_size(relid))) as total_size,
   pg_size_pretty(SUM(pg_indexes_size(relid))) as index_size,
   pg_size_pretty(SUM(pg_relation_size(relid))) as actual_size
FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables;


I get

And when I run
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(<MY_DB_NAME>));

I get

Because of this, our storage bill in RDS is massive, and I don't know what else to search for. Unfortunately, I don't have access to AWS Technical Support

Is this post:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/312473/how-to-clear-aws-rds-aurora-mysql-local-storage?rq=1  helpfull?

Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Why don't you have access to tech support?

Have you tried VACUUMing your system?

An obvious possibility is that isn't in the user table.  Do you have access to query all_tables or sys_tables?

@Vérace yes I tried VACUUM it cleared about 10GB of space

@Vérace I don't have access to AWS Tech Support because my company doesn't want to pay for it, unfortunately.

@jjanes I think I do have access, which query should I use to check this hypothesis?

@Martie I have about 33GB in FreeLocalStorage according to Cloudwatch, but my VolumeBytesUsed is 4.5TB

Just replace "user" in "pg_statio_user_tables" with "all" in your current query.  But be aware that your total_size column will then be double-counting the size of TOAST.
